# How to add another python sub-package to install?

Tags: python, package

I have a basic python package structure below. I installed the folder 'package_name_1' under site-packages after I ran pip install.

```
package_name/
    README.txt
    setup.py
    package_name_1/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
```

How should I install another folder so that after pip install I have both package_name_1 and package_name_2 installed:

```
package_name/
    README.txt
    setup.py
    package_name_1/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
    package_name_2/
          __init__.py
          module2.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have them both installed if you are relying on default pip Behavior.
But if you were relying on pip then you can use the `--target` option to pip, so the install location is changed and both modules won't have an import conflict.